# I’m trying to make two buttons that print two different things in swift playground

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

I’m new to swift and coding in general and I’m trying to make a truth or dare game but when I run the code using step through my code and press the red button it is running the code from Responder and not from responder1. I think the problem might be that I maid the 2nd button just by copying the for the 1st button and adding 1, and then swift thinks that the button 1 is the same as button and it runs the code for the 1st button.

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

//
let view = UIView()
view.backgroundColor =  #colorLiteral(red: 0.0, green: 0.7522757053375244, blue: 0.780606746673584, alpha: 1.0)
view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 300)


let lbl = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 0, width: 200, height: 50))
lbl.text = "Hello, World!"
view.addSubview(lbl)
lbl.textColor = .blue


let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 100, width: 100, height: 50))
button.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.721568644046783, green: 0.886274516582489, blue: 0.592156887054443, alpha: 1.0)
//button.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0), for: UIControlState.selected)
button.setTitle("button", for: UIControl.State.selected)
button.layer.cornerRadius = 10
view.addSubview(button)

let button1 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 250, y: 100, width: 100, height: 50))
button1.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 0.1893465518951416, blue: 0.1893465518951416, alpha: 1.0)
//button1.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0), for: UIControlState.selected)
button1.setTitle("button1", for: UIControl.State.selected)
button1.layer.cornerRadius = 10
view.addSubview(button1)


class Responser: NSObject
{
    
    //Method to be called
    @objc func printname()
    {
        lbl.text = "aha"
    }
}

let responder = Responser()
button.addTarget(responder, action: #selector(Responser.printname), for:.touchUpInside)  

class Responser1: NSObject
{
    
    //Method to be called
    @objc func printname()
    {
        lbl.text = "UAh"
    }
}

let responder1 = Responser()
button1.addTarget(responder1, action: #selector(Responser1.printname), for:.touchUpInside)


PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```

Comment: `let responder1 = Responser()` did you meant `let responder1 = Responser1()`? It would have been maybe better to change `printName()` into `printName1()` in `Responser1`, then you would have seen a crash explaining why it failed previously...